# span style change by class search

Tags: jquery, styles

What I want to do is change a style property of a span. I can get through a search of the child elements of a class,
but it did not change the style of that element. Here is my code:

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span").each(function ()
    {
         if($(this).attr("class") == "selectBox-label"){
            $(this).style.width = "70px"; //no change style a element

         }
    });
```

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: Use `$(this).hasClass('selectBox-label')` instead.

Comment: Use `$(this).style.width("70px");` instead as that's how you use this method..as defined here http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: `$(".cmbdiaclase > span.selectBox-label").width(70);` does the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span").each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('selectBox-label')){
        $(this).css('width', '70px'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it more jQuery style using an improved selector

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span.selectBox-label").css("width", "70px");
```

But keep in mind that you won't see any change to the CSS `width` property unless your `<span>` element has the CSS `display` property set to `block` or `inline-block`.

If you want to keep the same code then you can just change a few things in your original code. When setting CSS styles you should use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). When testing for a class you can use [`.hasClass(className)`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span").each(function ()
{
     if($(this).hasClass("selectBox-label"))
     {
        $(this).css("width", "70px");

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span").each(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('selectBox-label'){
             $(this).css('width', '70px');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you solution, you'll need to use the **CSS()** function to change the style.

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span").each(function ()
    {
         if($(this).hasClass("selectBox-label")){
            $(this).css('width','70px'); //no change style a element

         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

*Change:*

```
$(this).style.width = "70px"; //no change style a element
```

*To:*

```
$(this).style.width("70px");
```

As defined by jQuery's Documentation for [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> .width( value )
>
> value
>   Type: String or Number
>   An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer along with an optional unit of measure appended (as a string).

As everyone else mentioned you should also change your usage of:

```
if($(this).attr("class") == "selectBox-label"){
```

To:

```
if($(this).hasClass('selectBox-label')){
```

As defined by the jQuery documentation for [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

> Description: Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.
>   **.hasClass( className )**
>   className
>   Type: String
>   The class name to search for.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right:

```
$(".cmbdiaclase > span").each(function () {
    // use hasClass, instead of checking the attr("class"), this will only work if it has 1 class.
    if($(this).hasClass('selectBox-label')){
        // This is wrapped in a jQuery $( ) which makes it a jQuery object
        $(this).css('width', '70px');

        // Not wrapped in a jQuery $( ), it stays the DOM object. 
        this.style.width = "70px";  
    }
});
```

So it depends on how you use this in the context. Do you want a jQuery object or a DOM object.